# Latest version of Chrome disabled textfield input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Just about everyone at my company is having with last week's Chrome release build `75.0.3770.142`. There is a specific text field in a homegrown Java EE application that no longer takes input. Previous versions still work successfully, such as build `74.0.3729.169`. I've been looking through the `onkeypress` function call and it looks like the culprit is `window.event.returnValue`. Does anyone have more information? Is it deprecated or disabled? I was looking through the build logs and didn't see anything mentioned.

The following code is what it's running. It's used in the search process. I did not write it, it was written 14 years ago and the creator isn't with the company anymore. It's supposed to ensure that the user is on chrome and that their input is valid. I.e.: begins with an alphabetical character, no more than 4 chars long, and allows an asterisk to get all results:

```
function checkField(){
    if(!window.chrome){
        var sel = document.selection;
        if(sel){
            sel.clear();
        }   
    }else{
        if (window.getSelection) {  
            var sel = window.getSelection().toString();
            if(sel){
                sel.clear();

            }
         }

    }
    var key = window.event.keyCode;
    window.event.returnValue = false;
    // asterisk
    if (key == 42)
        window.event.returnValue = true;
    // first char
    if(window.event.srcElement.value.length == 0){
        // lowercase alphabetical char
        if ((key > 0x60) && (key < 0x7B)){
            window.event.keyCode = key-0x20;
            window.event.returnValue = true;
        / char already uppercase
        } else if((key > 0x40) && (key < 0x5B)){
            window.event.returnValue = true;
        }
    // last 3 chars are numerical
    } else if(window.event.srcElement.value.length > 0 && window.event.srcElement.value.length < 4){
        if(key >= 48 && key <= 57){
            window.event.returnValue = true;
        }
    }
    // line-feed and carriage return
    if(key == 10 || key == 13){
        window.event.returnValue = true;
    }
  }
```

When it hits the line `if (key == 42)` it executes the following line `window.event.returnValue = true;` on previous versions, but not the most up to date version. If I strip out all of the functionality and just set `window.event.returnValue = true;` then it does execute.

---

EDIT: Stephen's answer below is a good option to resolve the issue. In this case, it *was* that the chrome update from v74 to v75 broke the code — I assume because the code above was designed to be used with IE, so perhaps the new Chrome update disabled it; I'm not sure though.

Furthermore, it seemed that using `window.event.returnValue` and initializing it to `false` was a factor in the failure, and subsequent attempts to set it to true always failed. Instead, I opted to just `return true;` where it was previously set to `true`, and at the end of the method after my conditions, I execute `event.preventDefault();`. This acts as `return false;` by canceling the event, preventing successful validation. I also use the `event` object in the current scope rather than the `event` in `window` if possible:

`var event = this.event ? this.event : window.event;`

This should allow IE instances to execute successfully by pointing `event` to `window.event`.

Comment: Please provide some proof-of-example code.

Comment: @Brad I added the code.

Comment: Could you narrow this down to a specific reproducible example?  For what it's worth, I think you should take the time to rewrite this code.  Browsers have built-in validation these days.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)  Also, you're treading on thin ice a bit with how you're handling the events.  It's likely they'll break some day.  Rather than using `window.event`, use the event passed to handler function.  Rather than `event.returnValue`, use `event.preventDefault()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Brad. I'll give rewriting it a shot and see how it turns out. I thought that it being outdated was probably the problem since this is 14-year-old code, and I had seen a few things about `preventDefault()`, but didn't have a chance to dig deeper. If you want, turn your last comment into an answer and I'll accept it and update the OP with my results once I get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that uses no code at all. It uses HTML5 validation with a pattern: `[A-Za-z]{1,4}|\*`
The pattern says

```
[A-Za-z] => upper or lowercase alphabetical character
{1,4}    => repeated 1 to 4 times
|        => ...or...
\*       => a literal asterisk
```

I use the `required` attribute so the entry is not considered valid if it's empty.
The style simply tints the input's background red when it is `:invalid` or green when it is `:valid`

```css
input[type="search"]:invalid {
    background-color: rgb(255, 200, 200);
}

input[type="search"]:valid {
    background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <label for="searchbox">Search for:</label>
    <input type="search" name="searchbox" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,4}|\*" required>
    <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

You would probably *still* want to hook up some javascript to this -- maybe the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event to disable the search button when the input is invalid, then enable the button when it becomes valid, but if this is part of a form it would prevent form submission simply because the form contents are not valid.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I'll use your answer as a template to make the necessary changes to this code.